# Google Widevine CDM Plugin

Tags: firefox, opera, amazon

I have installed

```
$ firefox --version
Mozilla Firefox 53.0
```

on ubuntu

```
$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS
Release:    16.04
Codename:   xenial
```

After enable DRM checkbox in `about:preferences#content` I could find the CDM plugin under `about:addons`. But if I try to playback a video a message appears to contact service with respect to error code 7031. I called the service and they mentioned it is not possible to playback videos in Linux. Is that true?

Comment: Related: https://askubuntu.com/q/912544/367990

Comment: @ThomasWard I do have the CDM plugin in my list on Firefox 53 though. Can't confirm if it works though as I don't have access to any protected videos (or at least don't know where to look...)

Comment: @ByteCommander, I enabled DRM checkbox under `about:preferences#content` and the CDM plugin is now listed. But if I try to start the video I got a message that mentioned to contact service with respect to error code 7031. I called them and they said it will not work under Linux. Is that true?

Comment: Sorry, I neither know what exact technologies they use and whether or how it is possible to get that working on Linux. Unfortunately most proprietary web technologies for multimedia do not care offer optimal Linux support. That DRM checkbox was just what is needed to get the Widevine CDN plugin, but if Amazon does not use this, it doesn't help much.